# Does Android Management API WebTokens expire?

Tags: android-management-api

The Android Management API WebToken resource can only be created so I guess it is designed to expire at some time. What is the exact behavior as I did not find this information in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the web tokens generated using [enterprises.webTokens.create](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.webTokens/create) that identifies the enterprise. The lifetime of the token is limited to only a few 4 hours, so even though there is no API to expire, the token will only be active for a few hours.